# Rectangle not animating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my app all the listbox items are tiles,so I am using rectangles for the same.Now I want to add a little animation to rectangles when a list item is added.

Following is my code to rotate the triangle:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" x:Name="rectArticle">
                                <Rectangle.Projection>
                                    <PlaneProjection></PlaneProjection>
                                </Rectangle.Projection>
                                <Rectangle.Resources>
                                    <EventTrigger x:Name="event" RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard x:Name="rotate">
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectArticle">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0">
                                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Rectangle.Resources>
                            </Rectangle>
```

But what's happening is that all the listbox items(rectangle) appear at once without exhibiting any animation.Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added an `EventTrigger` simply under Resource section but never invoked it.

Instead of putting it under `Resource` section, you should put it under `Triggers` section.

```
<Rectangle.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger x:Name="event" RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
   ....
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```